# Continuous integration - git flow

Tags: java, jboss, continuous-integration, git-flow

I'm really nooby in 'Continuous integration'. And have a question about it.
Is it possible to create jar, ear or war file and deploy it on jboss every time I merge my develop branch (release) with master branch. I user gradle for build my project. I prefer something without user interface. My server runs on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a build server (like `Jenkins`) that could be configured to poll your `git` repository and run the build upon commit and on a successful build it would deploy (by a script or some plugin) the build product (jar/war) onto your `JBoss` server.